# Windows Server 2012 two out going connections

Tags: windows, networking, windows-server-2012-r2

I have a server with several Ethernet ports. I have the first 3 bridged together for the local network. The 4th is plugged into the modem which is giving it a public IPv4 address.

How do I tell the server which Ethernet port to use for in and out going traffic and to not go the switch/router route?

I would like the server to use the 4th port for internet access for remote access in and and out.

Comment: `How do I tell the server which Ethernet port to use for in and out going traffic and to not go the switch/router route?` - I don't understand this statement. `I would like the server to use the 4th port for internet access for remote access in and and out` - You should assign a Default Gateway to this interface. The other interfaces should not have a Default Gateway configured (Windows doesn't support multiple Default Gateways). Any non local traffic (not local to any interface) should transit the Default Gateway, which is the default behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use [Route.exe](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Bb490991.aspx) to specify the interfaces that should be used.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `route` command to make local traffic go through the bridged interfaces and non-local traffic through the modem.